# Android sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've been following [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/first-run) tutorial and i am stuck.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        firstRunPreferences();

        if(getFirstRun())
        {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "firstrun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setRunned();  
        }
        else
        {           
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "not firstrun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public boolean getFirstRun() {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
     }
    public void setRunned() {  
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        edit.commit();
     }
    public void firstRunPreferences() {
        Context mContext = Main.this.getApplicationContext();
        mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", 0); 
     }

}`
```

Everytime i run it in Eclipse it says "not firstrun". I guess the preferences reset every time the app is reinstalled, so what is wrong with the code? As far as i remember, i saw once "firstrun".

Thanks

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior on my Evo (now at 2.3.3) when i update after code change.  Also, a 1.6 Emulator.  I don't recall this ever behaving like this before.  My code is essentially the same as yours

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using the Emulator to run your app. Are you closing the emulator between runs?

Check if you have the "Wipe User Data" checkbox ticked in the Target tab of your Debug run configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: That doesn't help. I have to uninstall the app in the Emulator every time :(

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are not cleaned by uninstall.

If you want something cleaned after reinstall, put a field in your database.

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think SharedPreferences are removed when uninstalling, but not when updating an app.